# Hide a panel until a blur event is invoked

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

How to update the `style` on the second panelGrid while there is event blur invoked after user input a text on `licplate`? I tried the code below but it got error:

> ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-28][render_portlet_jsp:154]
>   javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with identifier
>   "panelInfo.Show()" referenced from

```
<p:panelGrid styleClass="noborder valigntop">
    <p:row>
        <p:column>
            <p:panelGrid styleClass="noborder">
                <p:row>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:inputText id="licplate" value="#{gateBacking.queue.fleet}" >
                            <p:ajax event="blur" update="panelInfo.Show();" />
                        </p:inputText>
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <p:panelGrid widgetVar="panelInfo" styleClass="border" style="visibility:hidden;">
                <p:row>
                    //---
                </p:row>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </p:column>
    </p:row>
</p:panelGrid>
```

Thanks!

---

**EDIT**

The code show the hidden panel, but after then, the button doesn't work.

```
...
<p:tab id="tabXXX" title="XXX"> 
    <h:form id="frmXXX">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function test(){
                 $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('frmXXX:opt')).css("display","block");
            }
        </script>

        <p:messages id="prmMessage" autoUpdate="false" closable="true" />

        <p:panelGrid id="pnlXXX">
            <p:row>
                <p:column>
                    <p:panelGrid>
                        <p:row>
                            <p:column><p:outputLabel for="valLbl" value="Value : " /></p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <p:inputText id="valLbl" value="#{...}" required="true">
                                    <p:ajax event="blur" update="olLicPlate" oncomplete="test();" />
                                </p:inputText>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column><p:message for="valLbl" display="icon" /></p:column>
                        </p:row>
                    </p:panelGrid>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <p:outputPanel id="opt" style="display:none;">
                        <p:panelGrid id="pnlInfo">
                            ...
                        </p:panelGrid>
                    </p:outputPanel>
                </p:column>
            </p:row>
            <p:row>
                <p:column colspan="2">
                    <p:panelGrid>
                        <p:row>
                            <p:column>
                                <p:commandButton id="btnAdd" value="Add"
                                    action="#{...}" process="@form"
                                    update="pnlXXX,prmMessage"></p:commandButton>
                            </p:column>
                        </p:row>
                    </p:panelGrid>
                </p:column>
            </p:row>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</p:tab>
...
```

Comment: You try: <p:ajax event="blur" oncomplete="panelInfo.Show();" />

Comment: @RongNK post an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`update` attribute is used for update components after an ajax call has completed. If you want to call some javascript function after an ajax call has completed, you have to use in `oncomplete` `onsuccessfull` or `onerror`(your option):

- In your circumstance,you try

  ```
  <p:ajax event="blur" oncomplete="panelInfo.show();" />

  <p:panel visible="false" widgetVar="panelInfo">
              //content here
  </p:panel>
  ```
- You can use outputPanel, i have tested with ajax:

  ```
       <h:form id="description">            
          <script type="text/javascript">
              function test(){
                   $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('description:opt')).css("display","block");
              }
          </script>
          <p:outputPanel id="opt" style="display:none;">
              <p:commandButton process="@this" value="test" actionListener="#{user.Test}"/>
          </p:outputPanel>
          <p:inputText id="licplate" value="zzzz" >
              <p:ajax event="blur" oncomplete="test();" />
          </p:inputText>
      </h:form>
  ```

Comment: Hi thanks! But unfortunately it doesn't work. The grid is hidden but while I tried to input some text and move to another inputText, the grid doesn't show up...

Comment: I have just updated my answer, you should use panel not panelgrid, and you use visible attribute, sorry for my mistake !

Comment: then I have to put the panelGrid between panel tag?

Comment: Yes, then you can change panel'css, it will look like not use Panel.

Comment: If you don't want Panel(just panelGrid), you should create javascript function, or use rendered attribute....

Comment: It works, but it affect the other function on the page. After the panel show, and the form can't submitted/another ajax function become disabled...

Comment: Did you have any exception(client/browser) ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes, I have post an update to the question. The code after show the hidden panel, then the submit button (btnAdd) doesn't work...

Comment: @mrjimoy_05: i would like to close this question, did you try my suggestion(don't use panel, alternative approach is OutputPanel) :)

Comment: Whoops, sorry.. I have updated the info. I have tried both ways and just the same, the button doesn't work after the hidden panel/OutputPanel show. Btw, thanks for your answer, at least it will help my another problem! ;)

Comment: You should post button in frmXXX:opt.